# How to remap fn modifier to another key modifier (on internal keyboard)?

Tags: macos, keyboard, catalina, keybindings

In Preferences > Keyboard > Key modifiers, I am able to remap (swap) all key modifiers (Command, Option, Ctrl) but Fn. Indeed, for the function modifier, the only choice where I can map it is precisely the function key.

So how could I remap Fn modifier to Ctrl key (on internal kbd) on 
Macbook Pro 10.15 ?

Comment: This is not Catalina specific.  On Mojave you also **can** map `Fn` **to** any other modifier key (Caps Lock, Ctrl, Option etc) but you **can't** map any of the other modifier keys to act as `Fn`.